# get default image name

Tags: ios

I have an app that needs to carry over the default.png image during the startup.  My app is internationalized, so I have a different image for each country, and have followed the guidelines for several options for the image (default, @2x versions, landscape, etc.)

So to the query, is it possible after startup to determine which version of the image was selected to be displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UILaunchImageFile"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: Thanks, but imageName consistently returns nil.

Comment: Just curious - do you define that key in your info.plist? If not then the default is 'Default.png', no? With that can you ask for the localized string for 'Default.png'? I don't think you can determine '@2x' or '~iPad', but if you look at the actual image you can get its scale and size, and with those reconstruct the rest.

Comment: No, not defined, I use the default naming convention provided by Apple.  I assume that there is some function that determines which image is used.

Comment: If you are not localizing the names, and you use the @2x and '~device' conventions, then you have to look at scale and size to know these two attributes to construct a file path. If you do not localize names, so all images are variants of 'Default', then to find the exact image you'll have to look at the localization info and determine yourself (I believe) what folder the image is coming from. With all this information you can then construct a file path. In my non-localized app, I re-use the Default image as a background view by asking UIImage for the imageNamed:@"Default.png".